# Retrieve the error message from a github actions failed job

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Assuming I have two jobs and the second depends on the first one:

```yaml
jobs:

  job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest 
  
    steps:
      - uses: somerepo/someaction@v1

      - uses: anotherrepo/anotheraction@v1

      - bash: shell
        run: |
          do-a-lot-of-stuff


  job-2:
    runs-on: ununtu-latest
    needs: job-1
    if: failure()

   steps:
     - shel: bash
       run: echo ${{ needs.job-1.fail.message }}
```

Is there a way to capture the failure message from `job-1`?

(from whichever step failed of course)

Comment: I'm looking for the same functionality, haven't found yet

Comment: Also, I'm looking for how to capture if the job was manually rejected https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77067726/how-to-check-if-the-job-was-rejected-in-github-actions-workflow